# Arduino automatic plant watering system

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have this code for a automatic watering system but the pump is permanently on, it is on even if the sensor detects humidity and is under 370.
I don't know why it does this but can someone help/ explain it to me?

This is the code, everything else works i have connected the right pins and co.

````
int b = 1800; //Zeit aus bzw. warten
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(analogRead(0),INPUT);
pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
if (analogRead(0) >370) {digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
delay(a);}
else if (analogRead(0) <370) {digitalWrite(13,LOW);
delay(b);}
int val = analogRead(0); //connect sensor to Analog 0
 Serial.println(val); //print the value to serial port
 delay(1000);
}```
````

Comment: One issue is that `pinMode(analogRead(0),INPUT);` in `setup()` should be `pinMode(0,INPUT);` - although the arduino will default the pin to an input. Also - you don't show the value of `a` used for the delay when you switch on the pump. One suggestion is to read the analog sensor value into a variable - print it out to serial - then use that variable for the condition so that you know exactly what value it is using. That might give you more of an idea what's going on rather than calling `analogRead()` multiple times.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestions and now I have this code:
`int c = analogRead(0);
int a = 1000;
int b = 1800; //Zeit aus bzw. warten
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(A0,INPUT);
pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
if (c >370) {digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
delay(a);}
else if (c <370) {digitalWrite(13,LOW);
delay(b);}
int d = analogRead(0);
Serial.println(d); //print the value to serial port
delay(1000);
}`

But the pump still pumps when it shouldn't.

Comment: You still need `int c = analogRead(A0);` at the top of the loop function not outside it. My suggestion was to read it into a variable - in this case `c` - and print out that variable to `Serial` before the `if` checks.  What values of `d` are you currently seeing? Do these look sensible?

Answer (score 0):

You initialized the Analog Channel using:

```
pinMode(analogRead(0),INPUT);
```

instead of

```
pinMode(A0,INPUT);
```

Thus, a pin is initialized given the result of analogRead(0) instead of initializing A0